# fedora default traffic monitor tool

Tags: network-monitoring, traffic

On a fedora server i have access using a ssh connection. As a regular user, how can I see what traffic is involved into the server?

I don't have root rights, and I'll like to learn from the default tools already installed. I assume that all I can use is a cli type tool.

Until now, I was playing with top (which is so cool comparing with ms windows tools), but I'll like to see/learn stuff about traffic too.

Answer (score 3):

There are many tools available to check the network traffic coming in/out of your server.

If you want to see bandwidth related information, you can use a tool like `ntop` or `nload`.

If you want to see detailed packets information (sniffing), you can use a tool like `tcpump` or `tshark`.

However, most of these tools (if not all) require root privileges. At least, you need to have them installed.

Comment: on any of them I get a 'command not found'

Comment: It seems that they are not installed. You can try them on another machine with root privileges :)

Comment: The utility name is `tcpdump` and not `tcpump`

Comment: @Developer: You are right! It is a typo :)

Comment: @khaled posted an excellent answer. I would like to add one important note. Never ever inspect your traffic on your production server.

If you happen to sniff your packets into .pcap file, for instance, make sure you encrypt it before you download it as it has raw packets data and then in you VirtualBox image inspect that file with WireShard for example. Since the .pcap file may include potentially dangerous binary data it may harm your workstation, be prepared for that.

VirtualBox provides you with a disposable instance that you don't care about that much.

Answer (score 2):

This will be nearly impossible without root rights. But if you ever manage to get it to work, IPTraf may be a useful tool for you.